# Modify Arguments of Already Registered Custom Post Type with Filter

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, arguments, custom-post-type

Im trying to set the `show_in_rest` argument on a custom post type that was already registered by a third party plugin from `false` to `true`. The plugin author thankfully included an arguments filter and provided an example (see below first code block). **Any idea how to set the mentioned argument to true?**

**This is the CPT register function**

```
    public function register_client() {

    $labels = apply_filters( 'business_manager_client_labels', array(
        'name'                  => _x( '%2$s', 'post type general name', 'business-manager' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( '%1$s', 'post type singular name', 'business-manager' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'New %1s', 'business-manager' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New %1$s', 'business-manager' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit %1$s', 'business-manager' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New %1$s', 'business-manager' ),
        'all_items'             => __( '%2$s', 'business-manager' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View %1$s', 'business-manager' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search %2$s', 'business-manager' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No %2$s found', 'business-manager' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No %2$s found in Trash', 'business-manager' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => '',
        'menu_name'             => _x( '%2$s', 'admin menu', 'business-manager' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter %2$s list', 'business-manager' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( '%2$s list navigation', 'business-manager' ),
        'items_list'            => __( '%2$s list', 'business-manager' ),
    ) );

    foreach ( $labels as $key => $value ) {
        $labels[ $key ] = sprintf( $value, business_manager_label_client_single(), business_manager_label_client_plural() );
    }

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => false,
        'show_in_rest'          => false,
        'exclude_from_search'   => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => false,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => false, // we are using custom add_submenu_page
        'query_var'             => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'          => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'supports'              => array( 'title' ),
    );

    register_post_type( 'bm-client', apply_filters( 'business_manager_client_post_type_args', $args ) );

}
```

**This is the provided example**

```
add_filter( 'business_manager_employee_post_type_args', 'example_function_for_employee_post_type', 10, 1 );

function example_function_for_employee_post_type( $args ) {
    print( $args ); //print the return value
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. you can access "show_in_rest" key in "$args" parameter and update the value by true.

```
add_filter( 'business_manager_employee_post_type_args', 'example_function_for_employee_post_type', 10, 1 );
function example_function_for_employee_post_type( $args ) {
    $args['show_in_rest'] = true;
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Thx - how to modify multiple args at once?

Comment: You can copy this " $args['show_in_rest'] = true;" same line and add new key to $args and set value to that.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to change this in any other CPT that does not have a predefined filter hook. CTP registration function already contains the required filter hook that may be used: `register_post_type_args`

So this becomes:

```php
add_action('register_post_type_args', function ($args, $postType) {
    if ($postType !== 'bm-client'){
        return $args;
    }

    $args['show_in_rest'] = true;

    return $args;
}, 99, 2);
```

Related article: https://zerowp.com/modify-cpt-arguments-after-it-was-registered/